# Content Type no showing fields

Tags: entities, nodes

I have been trying to created a content type programmatically in Drupal 7. I notice that I should use the [hook_node_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7) to generate the content type with the title and to add the body I should use the  `node_add_body_field`. I have been follow the [examples modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) ￼

So this is what I got as my code ...

**non_recruiter.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_node_info().
 */
function non_recruiter_node_info() {
  // We define the node type as an associative array.
  return array(
      'job_template_2' => array(
          'name' => t('Job Template 2'),
          'base' => 'job_template_2',
          'description' => t('A content type for posting your jobs.'),
          'title_label' => t('Job Template 2'),
          'locked' => TRUE,
      ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_type_insert().
 */
function non_recruiter_node_type_insert($content_type) {
  if ($content_type->type == 'job_template_2') {
      $body_instance = node_add_body_field($content_type, t('Job Description'));
        $body_instance['display']['non_recruiter_list'] = array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed',
    );

    // Save our changes to the body field instance.
    field_update_instance($body_instance);

    // Create all the fields we are adding to our content type.
    foreach (_non_recruiter_installed_fields() as $field) {
      field_create_field($field);
    }

    // Create all the instances for our fields.
    foreach (_non_recruiter_installed_instances() as $instance) {
      $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
      $instance['bundle'] = 'non_recruiter';
      field_create_instance($instance);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function non_recruiter_form($node, $form_state) {
  return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}


function _non_recruiter_installed_fields() {
  return array(
      'non_recruiter_quantity' => array(
          'field_name'  => 'node_example_quantity',
          'cardinality' => 1,
          'type'        => 'text',
      ),
  );
}


function _non_recruiter_installed_instances() {
  return array(
      'non_recruiter_quantity' => array(
          'field_name'  => 'non_recruiter_quantity',
          'label' => t('Quantity required'),
          'type'        => 'text',
          'widget'      => array(
              'type'    => 'text_textfield',
          ),
          'display' => array(
              'non_recruiter_list' => array(
                  'label' => 'hidden',
                  'type' => 'hidden',
              ),
          ),
      ),
  );
}
```

So I took what they did and modify the code base on what I want.

My Goal is to have a content type that have the following fields...

- Job Title (title)
- Job Description (body)
- Quantity (text)

But I'm doing something wrong because the fields are empty. If I try to add new content using this content type this is what I got ... [image: Empty Content type]

An empty content type, without any fields.

Here is some extra information of how my Manage Fields & Display looks like.. 
**Manage Fields**[image]

**Manage Display**

[image]

So, can anyone tell me why my fields are not showing up in my content type ?

Comment: Any chance you've installed the module, then added `hook_node_type_insert()` afterwards? If so it won't be run. Might be worth uninstalling and re-installing the module to check

Comment: I have uninstalling and re-installing the module few times already. And just in case I did it again, but this did not fix my problem. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Core modules (like Blog) seem to do it in `hook_install()` rather than the insert hook - you could try using the same method as https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.install/function/blog_install/7. It may be a case of adding `node_types_rebuild();` to the top of the insert hook instead. Though that doesn't seem right thinking about it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_info().
 */
function non_recruiter_node_info() {
  // We define the node type as an associative array.
  return array(
      'job_template_2' => array(
          'name' => t('Job Template 2'),
          'base' => 'job_template_2',
          'description' => t('A content type for posting your jobs.'),
          'title_label' => t('Job Template 2'),
          'locked' => TRUE,
      ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_type_insert().
 */
function non_recruiter_node_type_insert($content_type) {
  if ($content_type->type == 'job_template_2') {
      $body_instance = node_add_body_field($content_type, t('Job Description'));
        $body_instance['display']['non_recruiter_list'] = array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed',
    );

// Save our changes to the body field instance.
field_update_instance($body_instance);

// Create all the fields we are adding to our content type.
foreach (_non_recruiter_installed_fields() as $field) {
  field_create_field($field);
}

// Create all the instances for our fields.
foreach (_non_recruiter_installed_instances() as $instance) {
  $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
  $instance['bundle'] = 'job_template_2';
  field_create_instance($instance);
}
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function job_template_2_form($node, $form_state) {
  return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}


function _non_recruiter_installed_fields() {
  return array(
      'non_recruiter_quantity' => array(
          'field_name'  => 'node_example_quantity',
          'cardinality' => 1,
          'type'        => 'text',
      ),
  );
}


function _non_recruiter_installed_instances() {
  return array(
      'non_recruiter_quantity' => array(
          'field_name'  => 'node_example_quantity',
          'label' => t('Quantity required'),
          'type'        => 'text',
          'widget'      => array(
              'type'    => 'text_textfield',
          ),
          'display' => array(
              'non_recruiter_list' => array(
                  'label' => 'hidden',
                  'type' => 'hidden',
              ),
          ),
      ),
  );
}
```

Comment: There is unmatched value for key 'field_name' => 'non_recruiter_quantity' in the function _non_recruiter_installed_fields() and _non_recruiter_installed_instances() do it similar as you wanna
also replace  bundle name  $instance['bundle'] = 'non_recruiter'; to  $instance['bundle'] = 'job_template_2';
improvement:if you want to see your node type in UI under(http://your/domain/admin/structure/types/)  replace non_recruiter_form to job_template_2_form (as you are using 'base' => 'job_template_2')
I have tested. problem resolved.